# Change TextBox Foreground on focus in VisualState

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to change the `Foreground` of a `TextBox` in `Silverlight3` using `VisualState` in the `Resources`. The code below is what I have tried so far. But it didn't work. Please guide me.

```
<TextBox x:Name="EmailTextBox" Text="{Binding UserName, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxEmailStyle}"/>
```

And here is the referenced `Style` for the `TextBox` above:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxEmailStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.3"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                  <ColorAnimation
                                    Duration="0" To="#00000000"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContentElement.Foreground).
                            (SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="Border"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Opacity="1">
                        <Grid>
                          <Border x:Name="ReadOnlyVisualElement"
                              Background="#5EC9C9C9"
                              Opacity="0"/>
                          <Border x:Name="MouseOverBorder"
                              BorderBrush="Transparent"
                              BorderThickness="1">
                              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                  <Image
                                      Width="40"
                                      Source="/Images/sign_in_email.png"
                                      Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
                                  <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement"
                                      BorderThickness="0"
                                      IsTabStop="False"
                                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      Margin="4"/>
                              </StackPanel>
                          </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Storyboard.TargetProperty` was not correct, and you need to provide a default state "Unfocused" without the `Foreground` change (or you can never go back to "normal").

```
<VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
<VisualState x:Name="Focused">
    <Storyboard>
        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#00000000"
            Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

And btw: the color #00000000 will not be visible, maybe you want to change it to #FF000000

And make sure the Foreground is actually set to a `SolidColorBrush` instance by default:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" Foreground="White" ... />
```

Usually when one wants to change the `Template` of a control you would include all `VisualStates` that are defined for this control. So try to add those states, maybe the `VisualState` update method exits because [the other TextBox states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645061%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) are not defined.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Focused">...</VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
    </VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly"/>
    </VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused"/>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

**Edit:** OK, so you say this is working in SL4 but not in SL3? Well, have a look at the [features added with SL4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772166%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and see if you find anything that explains why the Template doesn't work in SL3 correctly but does so with SL4.

Comment: I made the changes you mentioned but it didn't work!

Comment: How does this "not working" present itself? Just no color change on `Focused` or do you get any exceptions?

Comment: @Mini-Con: Try to add missing `VisualStates`, see my extended answer.

Comment: Yes, I do added all visual states. But the thing is the code is working in silverlight 4 but not in silverlight 3.

Comment: @Mini-Con: added a hopefully helpful link.